# How to call this Symbols? "<" and ">"

Tags: symbols

Question is on top.

Idk how to call this Symbols: <>

I use it a lot in HTML but i asked myself never how to call it, and ive never saw the name of these symbols.

Now its time for that :D

Thanks for the Answers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less-than_sign, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater-than_sign

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities in HTML, I would call them "less than" and "greater than" symbols, respectively. They are also similar to angle brackets "⟨", "⟩".